# Interaction between main.cpp and mainwindow.cpp

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

I am dealing with image processing in Qt, using OpenCV. The image processing is dealed in `main.cpp`, after got some test objects, it goes to the mainwindows.cpp to show the interface to acquire data and make some analyzes.
After this is done, I need to go back to main.cpp to make another image processing.

But how do I send information from the mainwindow.cpp to the main.cpp?

This information will be on a loop for a webcam image. I already tried to use w.getInformation inside this loop but it causes a crash. In fact I only need to chaNge it on the main when the mainwindow wants it, not for every frame of the loop.

How am I supposed to do that?

Comment: I say this is an XY problem. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Execute your image processing from a slot of your QMainWindow not directly from `int main()`

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest moving your image processing code from the main.cpp to a different class. In your main, create instances of the image processing class and the mainwindow class.

In your mainwindow class connect the suitable mainwindow signal to a slot of the image processing class. Read on Qt's `SIGNALs and SLOTs` mechanism.